Trying to integrate MQTT into Alexa AWS Lambda function
I am trying to get my Alexa skill to publish to an MQTT Broker in the lambda code. However it only publishes sporadically. Could somebody tell me what I am missing? Here is my code:
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const mqtt = require("mqtt");


const protocol = 'mqtt'
const host = 'm21.cloudmqtt.com'
const port = '14297'
const clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`

const connectUrl = `${protocol}://${host}:${port}`
console.log(connectUrl);
const client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl, {
  clientId,
  clean: false,
  connectTimeout: 4000,
  username: '****',
  password: '***',
  reconnectPeriod: 1000,
})
client.on('connect',  function(connack) { 
        console.log("MQTT Client connected " + JSON.stringify(connack));
        // publish a message to a topic
        client.publish('/IoTmanager/YardESP/Garage_close3/control', '{"status":0}', function() {
            console.log("Message is published");
            client.end(); // Close the connection when published
        });

        });
client.on('end', () => { 
  console.log('Connection to MQTT broker ended');
});
//
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Would you like to open ur shut the Garage Door?';
    console.log("MQTT Connecting");
    /*client.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("MQTT Connected");
        client.publish("presence", "Hello mqtt");
    });*/

    //
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Would you like to open ur shut the Garage Door?', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const GarageDoorCloseIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
      && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GarageDoorCloseIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Closing The garage door!';
    console.log("MQTT Options: ", speechText);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Closing The garage door!', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const GarageDoorOpenIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
      && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GarageDoorOpenIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Opening The garage door!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Opening The garage door!', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const HelpIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
      && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'You can ask me the weather!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('You can ask me the weather!', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
      && (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
        || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Goodbye!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Goodbye!', speechText)
      .withShouldEndSession(true)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    // Any clean-up logic goes here.
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  }
};
const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Sorry, I don\'t understand your command. Please say it again.')
      .reprompt('Sorry, I don\'t understand your command. Please say it again.')
      .getResponse();
  }
};
let skill;

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  console.log(`REQUEST++++${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  console.log(context);
  if (!skill) {
    skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
      .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        GarageDoorCloseIntentHandler,
        GarageDoorOpenIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
      )
      .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
      .create();
  }


  const response = await skill.invoke(event, context);
  console.log(`RESPONSE++++${JSON.stringify(response)}`);

  return response;
};

I try invoking the Alexa skill and I get a proper response from/to Alexa but only sporadic messages publishing to the MQTT Broker.

Ok I have resolved my issue thanks to these two answers. How to use async functions within Alexa skill properly? and https://github.com/mqttjs/async-mqtt. It looks like the MQTT has to be wrapped in a async funtion a bit like this:
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const mqtt = require("mqtt");

var options = {
    port: 14297,
    username: "****",
    password: "***",
    connectTimeout: 3000,
    debug: true
};

var client;

LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Would you like to open ur shut the Garage Door?';


        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Would you like to open ur shut the Garage Door?', speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const GarageDoorCloseIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
            Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GarageDoorCloseIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Closing the garage door!';
        client = await mqtt.connectAsync('mqtt://m21.cloudmqtt.com', options);
        try {
            await client.publish("wow/so/cool", "It works!");
            // This line doesn't run until the server responds to the publish
            await client.end();
            // This line doesn't run until the client has disconnected without error
            console.log("Done");
        } catch (e) {
            // Do something about it!
            console.log(e.stack);
            process.exit();
        }
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Closing the garage door!', speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const GarageDoorOpenIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
            Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GarageDoorOpenIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Opening the garage door!';
        client = await mqtt.connectAsync('mqtt://m21.cloudmqtt.com', options);
        try {
            await client.publish("wow/so/cool", "It works!");
            // This line doesn't run until the server responds to the publish
            await client.end();
            // This line doesn't run until the client has disconnected without error
            console.log("Done");
        } catch (e) {
            // Do something about it!
            console.log(e.stack);
            process.exit();
        }

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Opening The garage door!', speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
            Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'You can ask me to open or shut garage door!';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('You can ask me to open or shut garage door!', speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
            (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent' ||
                Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Goodbye!';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Goodbye!', speechText)
            .withShouldEndSession(true)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        // Any clean-up logic goes here.
        client = await mqtt.connectAsync('mqtt://m21.cloudmqtt.com', options);
        try {
            await client.publish("wow/so/cool", "It works!");
            // This line doesn't run until the server responds to the publish
            await client.end();
            // This line doesn't run until the client has disconnected without error
            console.log("Done");
        } catch (e) {
            // Do something about it!
            console.log(e.stack);
            process.exit();
        }
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
    }
};
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak('Sorry, I don\'t understand your command. Please say it again.')
            .reprompt('Sorry, I don\'t understand your command. Please say it again.')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
let skill;

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    console.log(`REQUEST++++${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    if (!skill) {
        skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
            .addRequestHandlers(
                LaunchRequestHandler,
                GarageDoorCloseIntentHandler,
                GarageDoorOpenIntentHandler,
                HelpIntentHandler,
                CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
                SessionEndedRequestHandler,
            )
            .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
            .create();
    }


    const response = await skill.invoke(event, context);
    console.log(`RESPONSE++++${JSON.stringify(response)}`);


    return response;
};


Is it possible that you have it connected to 2 different subnets, one of which does not have a route to the Internet?
Out of curiosity, I ran your question through Amazon Q Developer (free tier):

What are some reasons that a Lambda function might have sporadic problems connecting to a service on the Internet?

There are several reasons why a Lambda function might experience sporadic issues connecting to a service on the Internet. Let's explore some of the common causes: 1
VPC Configuration: If your Lambda function is connected to a VPC, it may lose internet access. When a function is in a VPC, all outbound requests go through the VPC. To access the internet, the VPC needs to be configured correctly with a NAT gateway in a public subnet to allow outbound traffic. [2]
Cold Starts: Lambda functions that haven't been invoked for a while may experience "cold starts." During a cold start, the Lambda environment is being set up, which can cause delays and potentially lead to timeouts when trying to connect to external services.
DNS Resolution Issues: Sporadic DNS resolution problems can occur, especially if the Lambda function is making many requests in a short time. This can lead to intermittent connection failures. [3]
Rate Limiting: If your Lambda function is making frequent requests to an external service, you might hit rate limits imposed by that service. This can result in sporadic connection failures or timeouts.
Network Congestion: Temporary network congestion or routing issues in AWS's infrastructure or the public internet can cause intermittent connectivity problems.
Resource Constraints: If your Lambda function is running low on memory or hitting its execution time limit, it may struggle to establish or maintain connections consistently.
Elastic Network Interface (ENI) Limits: Lambda creates an ENI for each combination of subnet and security group attached to the function. If you're approaching the limit (default is 250 per VPC), you might experience sporadic connectivity issues.
Third-Party Service Issues: The external service you're trying to connect to might be experiencing its own intermittent problems or downtime.
Security Group Configuration: If your Lambda is in a VPC, ensure that the associated security group allows outbound traffic to the internet.
Concurrent Executions: If your function is experiencing high concurrency, you might hit Lambda service quotas, which could lead to sporadic failures.
To troubleshoot these issues, you can:
Review your VPC configuration if applicable.
Implement proper error handling and retry mechanisms in your code.
Use AWS X-Ray to trace requests and identify where failures are occurring.
Monitor your function's performance metrics in CloudWatch.
Implement logging to capture more details about the connection issues.
[Code example in Python]
This example implements a simple retry mechanism with exponential backoff, which can help mitigate some of the sporadic connection issues. Remember to adjust the max_retries and retry_delay values based on your specific needs and the characteristics of the service you're connecting to.
